# Unit Testing HTTP Interceptors

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-http-interceptors

I am using HTTP interceptor to show a loader every time any HTTP request is made from my page. Here is the implementation of the interceptor.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];
constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {}

removeRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const i = this.requests.indexOf(req);
    if (i >= 0) {
      this.requests.splice(i, 1);

    }
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(this.requests.length > 0);
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.requests.push(req);
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const subscription = next.handle(req)
        .subscribe(
        event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.removeRequest(req);
            observer.next(event);
          }
        },
        err => { this.removeRequest(req); observer.error(err); },
        () => { this.removeRequest(req); observer.complete(); });

      return () => {
        this.removeRequest(req);
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      };
    });
```

}
}

It works well and I would like to unit test it.

All I am doing is, whenever a HTTP request is made I am setting the `isLoading` flag to true.

I need to write an unit test for this. I went through lot of HTTP interceptor testing, but they are focused around testing the HTTP request by modifying it (like adding header, etc).

I want to know how can I test whether the flag is set whenever any HTTP request is made.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Any solution for this?